# Can we get dynamic value from angular in SCSS file

Tags: angularjs, sass

Basically I want to use background color for each element as per user choice, user choice will be stored on database. User should webpage according to it's color profile. So, I need a idea to get that value from angular and store its value on scss variable and render it.

Answer (score 1):

SCSS is a preprocessor, when you use SCSS it actually gets compiled into CSS and that's what you use.

Perhaps the best solution is to use [ngStyle](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle) in the section you need.. `body`, `div`, or anywhere you want..

Example

```
<div ng-style="userStyle">
...
</div>
```

In your JS

```
$scope.userInfo = { backgroundColor: 'red' };
$scope.userStyle = {'background-color': $scope.userInfo.backgroundColor};
```

Assuming you have a `userInfo` object, with `backgroundColor` property.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, angular is javascript code and runs in the clients browser, sass is pre-compiled to css, any variables will have been converted into the full values before it is rendered in the browser.

You would need to get angular to make a call to your server, and have the server generate a CSS file dynamically based on the value provided from angular. (I suppose you could do this on the client also, I'm sure there is a javascript library somewhere that lets you compile sass)

Answer (score 0):

Scss compiled to css before build, so angular part can't control scss. You can use gulp/grunt to edit scss variables. But in your case it not helping.

The simple sulotion for you is to use ng-style.

`<div ng-style="{'background-color': scopeUserColor}"><div\>`